# Why are JWE tokens not more widely used than JWT tokens?

Tags: authentication, security, browser, jwt, session-cookies

I'm learning about different web authentication mechanisms such as using JWTs or session IDs to maintain a user's authentication state.

I understand that JWT tokens don't secure any relevant user information in the payload. If this information includes user IDs, user claims and such, this seems like a considerable vulnerability given this is stored on the browser and therefore relying on a user's device security for protection.

I understand there are ways to keep JWTs secure (not saving in session/local storage and only saving them in memory, or transmitting them as cookies with the appropriate security attributes), but having unencrypted user information stored still seems an unnecessary vulnerability, especially if all this information is used by the server to determine the user's profile, as opposed to just looking it up from a secured database as would be done with session ID authentication.

From what I've read JWE tokens keep this user specific information secure, although I can find far less information available on their implementation compared to JWTs.

So why are JWEs not more widely adopted? I've found examples of security breaches involving JWT use that would have been prevented with JWEs.